# How to connect to hive databases in spark Using Java

Tags: apache-spark, hive, thrift

I am able to connect to hive using `hive.metastore.uris` in Sparksession. What I want is to connect to a particular database of hive with this connection so that I don't need to add database name to each table names in queries. Is there any way to achieve this ?

Expecting code something like

```
SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession.config("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://dhdhdkkd136.india.sghjd.com:9083/hive_database")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the catalog API accessible from the SparkSession.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.catalog.Catalog

You can then call `sparkSession.catalog.setCurrentDatabase(<db_name>)`